# Meaning of outing against

Tags: usage

What is the meaning of **outing against** in the following sentence

Off-spinner Ashwin joins Tamil Nadu to take on Gujarat at Just Cricket ground, and opening batsman Mayank joins his Karnataka mates in their M. Chinnaswamy Stadium ***outing against Chhattisgarh***.

I looked up it’s meaning but didn’t find anything satisfactory. Somebody help me

Answer (score 2):

An 'outing' in British English (India was a British colony) is a trip or visit - e.g. an outing to the zoo, to the seaside, to a park, etc. In a sports context, it can mean to a visit by a team to a stadium or ground for a match. Karnataka is a cricket team. They played a match against Chhattisgarh (another cricket team) at the M. Chinnaswamy Stadium.

> Outing countable noun
>
> In sport, an outing is an occasion when a player [or team] competes in a
>   particular contest or competition.
>
> *Playing in England's first outing, he suffered a whiplash injury to his neck.*

[Outing (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outing)

Comment: Similarly meaning **1** given in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/outing) and specifically in **1.2**.

Answer (score 1):

*M. Chinnaswamy Stadium* modifies *outing*, so let’s ignore that for a moment:

> ... opening batsman Mayank joins his Karnataka mates in their outing against Chhattisgarh.

Maybe you’re seeing *outing against* as a phrasal verb, but it’s not.

> [outing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outing)
>   2 : an athletic competition or race
>   also : an appearance therein
>   (M-W)

So *outing* roughly means *competition* or *match* in this case.

In *M. Chinnaswamy Stadium outing*, we understand M. Chinnaswamy Stadium to be the location of the match.

In *against Chhattisgarh*, *against* is used in the usual way to indicate the opponent, Chhattisgarh.